# Number picker not working in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout

`recycler_viewholder.xml` is the viewholder for `RecyclerView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <NumberPicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></NumberPicker>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`RecyclerView` Adapter to add `viewholder` to the `Recyclerview`.

```
package dallasco.scorecarts.adapters;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.AssetManager;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;


    public class SubTBGAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubTBGAdapter.TBGViewHolder> {


        private static final String TAG = "Hi";
        private static int viewHolderCount;
        private int mNumberItems;
        private String[] fileNames;
        private Context context;
        private View.OnClickListener listener;
        private int questionNo;
        private String tbgType;

        public SubTBGAdapter() {
            super();
        }

        public SubTBGAdapter(int numOfItems) {
            mNumberItems = numOfItems;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return super.getItemId(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TBGViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.bind(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mNumberItems;
        }



        @NonNull
        @Override
        public TBGViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
            Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
            boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_viewholder, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
                Log.e("CreatingViewHolder", viewHolderCount + "");
                TBGViewHolder tbgViewHolder = new TBGViewHolder(view, layoutIdForListItem, viewHolderCount);
                viewHolderCount++;
                return tbgViewHolder;
            }
            public TBGViewHolder(View itemView, int layoutId, int index) {


            void bind(int listIndex) {
    //            Log.e("List Index", Integer.toString(listIndex));
                //textView.setText(questions.get(listIndex).getStatement());]
            }


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }




    }
```

The Recycler view populates but the numberpicker inside the viewholder doesn't work.

The `recyclerview` is working fine it populates the `viewholders`. However the numberpicker inside the `viewholder` doesn't scroll it is rather frozen.
'

Comment: What is this `layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.recycler_viewholder.xml;`? And why are you not just using doing this `inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_viewholder, viewGroup, false);`?

Comment: I was previously using two layouts for the same recyclerview based on what file is it.

Comment: But, your code does not even compile using `int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.recycler_viewholder.xml;` in Android Studio 3.2.1

Comment: I have fixed the adapter. Can you try now? Thanks.

Comment: I must admit, I have never seen anyone implement an `Adapter` for a `RecyclerView`like this... According to your `Adapter` code you have not defined `TBGViewHolder` to be a `public class` which extends the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` .... your code fits no pattern that I have seen.